# Using @login_required without "?next=/" appended to the URL

Tags: python, django, redirect

I'm using the @login_required decorator in such a way:

```
@login_required(login_url=reverse_lazy('login'))
def my_view:
```

Now I know I could specify the login URL in the settings, but that's not my question. The thing is after it redirects to my 'login' URL, it appends `?next=` to it, like so:

```
http://whatever.com/login/?next=/fakeurl/
```

I don't want it. Is there a way to override this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass an additional parameter `redirect_field_name=None` to `login_required` decorator.

```
@login_required(login_url=reverse_lazy('login'), redirect_field_name=None)
def my_view(request): ...
```

This will remove the `?next=` portion in the URL.